# Filter datefield by day give error "user-defined function raised exception"

Tags: django, date

When i filter a DateField by day or month or both:

```
today = date.today()
birthday = Paziente.objects.filter(natoil__month=today.month, natoil__day=today.day)
```

Models

```
class Paziente(models.Model):
    natoil = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

give error:

```
OperationalError at /
user-defined function raised exception
```

Please Help
Django 1.11.4

Comment: can you add the models as well as the import for the date

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace? i dont think that query line is actually giving you the error

Comment: solved, there were some empty DateField()
Setted Null, filtered and work